# why modifying the data field change the other field in link list

Tags: c, struct

I want to insert node one by one in createDDCL() method and print all elements in printDDClinkList() method,but there is some strange error in createDDCL() method:

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
//BiDirection link list
typedef struct DDCL{
    int data;
    struct DDCL *priv;
    struct DDCL *next;
}*BiDirectionLink;


BiDirectionLink createDDCL(){//带头结点的双向循环链表
    int n = 0,i=0;
    BiDirectionLink head = (BiDirectionLink)malloc(sizeof(BiDirectionLink));
    BiDirectionLink newNode,lastNodw;

    head->next = head;
    head->priv = head;
    lastNodw = head;
    printf("how many node do you want?\n:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (; i<n; i++) {//append new node to the last
        newNode = (BiDirectionLink)malloc(sizeof(BiDirectionLink));
        newNode->priv = lastNodw;
        newNode->next = head;//new node's next always head
        head->priv = newNode;//th privious one of the head always the last
        lastNodw->next = newNode;
        newNode->data = i;
        lastNodw = newNode;       
    }
    return head;
}
```

detail!!!!!!!!!!!

```
void printDDClinkList(BiDirectionLink head){
    BiDirectionLink node = head->next;
    while (node->next != head) {
        printf("%d ",node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

void testDDCLinkList(){
    printDDClinkList(createDDCL());
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    testDDCLinkList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remove all casts where you don't know **exactly** what you are doing and can explain why the cast is **neccessary** for correct working. Never muzzle the compiler, instead ask it to speak up: Use `-Wall -Wextra`, and handle all warnings appropriately.

Comment: Your print function `printDDClinkList` is wrong. It does not print the node directly before the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem: You are allocating only enough memory for a **pointer**, not the whole **struct**.

This is what you did:

```
newNode = (BiDirectionLink)malloc(sizeof(BiDirectionLink));
```

Which is the same as this:

```
newNode = (struct DDCL *)malloc(sizeof(struct DDCL *));
```

But, that's what you wanted to do:

```
newNode = (struct DDCL *)malloc(sizeof(struct DDCL));
```

My recommendation? Never `typedef` to pointers.